# how do you get the name of the current route with Meteor Iron Router?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm struggling to find a way to access the 'name' property of a given route.  Currently I'm wanting to do this in a route, but plan on moving this code into a controller, so if its slightly different in these two instances I'd appreciate an example of both.

Basically I have the a number of routes that look like the following :

```
Router.route('/settings/:page?', {
    name : 'settings',
    controller : 'AppController',
    data : function() {
        return Meteor.user();
    },
    action : function() {
        this.render('settingsHeader',{to : "contentHeader"});
        if (this.params.page) {
            this.render('settings'+this.params.page);
        } else {
            this.render('settingsbasic');
        }
    }
});
```

I'd like to get the name of the given route, so that I can replace the strings where I'm naming the route (in this case settings).  Ultimately this would allow me to create a SubPageController which would neaten up my router code substantially.

This may be super simple, but I'm not finding exactly what I'm after in other SO questions or in the documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried Router.current().route.getName()?

Comment: I hadn't, but thats clearly it, thank you.

Comment: @DavidWeldon thank you, after reading the other question I see that, but the title asks something different, which is why I didn't dig in too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have it:

iron-router > 1.0

```
var routeName = Router.current().route.getName();
```

iron-router < 1.0

```
var routeName = Router.current().route.name;
```

Comment: Great job, dunno how I missed that. cheers.

Comment: @Ovidiu in the future, please indicate that a question is a duplicate rather than copying an existing answer.

Comment: @DavidWeldon. That's really strange :D. Haven't searched for the answer on SO but now that you mention it... it's really awkward we both came with the same identical answer... Next time I'll search for an answer before posting one. Thanks for the observation though